# Asp.NET cookie across subdomains not updating and not expiring

Tags: cookies, subdomain

I have 2 subdomains and I need to set and read the same cookie from both websites.

When I use localhost, everything works fine.

When I switch to using valid urls, the cookie infomation is not really being updated when I update it (expire date on logout).

I have the domain of the cookie set to ".mysite.com"

what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to set the domain to the cookie when expiring it on logout

```
HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["Token"];
aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
aCookie.Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CookieDomain"];
Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code: (works fine on localhost but not subdomain, never logs the user out because the cookie doesnt get expired)

Login page:

```
  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName.Text, true);
    // set the active collab cookie
    Member member = MemberManager.GetMemberByUsername(UserName.Text);

    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Token", member.Profile.Token);
    cookie.Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CookieDomain"];
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Globax ASAX

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Token"] != null) {
        string token = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Token"].Value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token)) {
                // If the user is logged in with a different token
                // or not logged in at all
                // then log them in with the token from the cookie
                if ((MemberManager.CurrentMember != null && MemberManager.CurrentMember.Profile.Token != token) || User == null) {

                  Member member = MemberManager.GetMemberByToken(token);
                  if (member != null) {
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(member.User.UserName, true);
                 }
             }
                }
            }
```

Logout Code:

```
 if (Request.Cookies["Token"] != null) {
                HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["Token"];
                aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
}
```

Web.Config

```
 <machineKey
      validationKey="{-snip-}"
      decryptionKey="{-snip-}"
      validation="SHA1"
      decryption="AES" />

 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="AuthCookie"
             path="/"
             loginUrl="~/login.aspx"
             protection="All"
             timeout="60">
      </forms>
    </authentication>
```

Comment: First: you should update your question, not post an aswer. 
observations: typically you do not have to set the cookie domain. Cookies are accessible throughout a TLD (top level domain) and do not need massaging in this way. If your apps are in different TLD then it is just not going to work, although i suspect this is not your problem. Also, I cannot understand what you are trying to accomplish so I probably will not be able to help you. It seems that you are implementing FormsAuthentication in parallel to another authentication managment strategy. What are your reasons for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if (Request.Cookies["Token"] != null) {
                HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["Token"];
                aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                Response.Cookies["Token"] = aCookie;
}
```

Instead of adding it, set it to the existing cookie.

Comment: I get this error
'System.Web.HttpCookieCollection.this[string]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Answer (score 0):

Your forms authentication setting in the web.config needs to enable cross app redirects:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="960" name=".ASPXAUTH" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="false" defaultUrl="~/default.aspx" enableCrossAppRedirects="true"/>
</authentication>
```